# Assembler MASM, printing in JNZ loop when value is 0 or below

Tags: loops, assembly, masm

I'v got a a task to write a program which would create below as output:

```
ABCD******
   ABCD***
      ABCD
```

My code is:

```
kod segment
org 100h
assume cs:kod

start:
mov cx,3
mov bx,3
mov ax,6

mov ah, 02h

    PETLA_ZEW:

    push cx
    mov cx,4
    mov dl, 'A'

        PETLA_CIAG:

            int 21h
            inc dl
            dec cx

        jnz PETLA_CIAG

    push ax
    mov cx, ax
    mov dl, '*'

        PETLA_GWIAZD:

            int 21h
            dec cx

        jnz PETLA_GWIAZD

    sub ax, 3

    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h

    push bx
    mov cx, bx
    mov dl, ' '
        PETLA_SPACJE:

            int 21h
            dec bx

        jnz PETLA_SPACJE

    pop bx
    add bx, 3

    pop cx
    dec cx

    jnz PETLA_ZEW

koniec:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
kod ends
end start
```

but the problem is that in loop called PETLA_GWIAZD when I subtract ax 2nd time it's value is 0, which is causing the infinite loop. Is there any other loop I should use when subtracting? Maybe some validation check just before the loop? I just started working with Assembly and still do not know a lot...

Thanks!

Comment: What you want is to output zero stars, when `ax` is zero. So your idea of "validation check just before the loop" sounds good to me. And there's reasonably simple way to do it. After `mov cx,ax` you can add `jcxz SKIP_GWIAZD`, and add new label `SKIP_GWIAZD:` after `sub ax,3` ahead of `print <new line>` code part. Here is description of different conditional jumps: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/5808/control-flow/20470/conditional-jumps#t=201612021937306141986

Comment: Oh, actually the `jcxz` is not described there, wow. Sorry. [Here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html) are some docs including `jcxz`.

Comment: Yeah, I just started reading more about other jumps, tried several variants + your idea but it still does not seem to work. I added    {jcxz} {SKIP_GWIAZD}     after    {mov cx, ax}    and actual    {SKIP_GWIAZD:}    
just before end of program which is    {koniec:}    but it still does not work. I did it this way because the last thing in last line are only letters, so we do not want to have anything after that (next line nor empty spaces).

Comment: Sorry, got a problem formating... 

Yeah, I just started reading more about other jumps, tried several variants + your idea but it still does not seem to work. I added `jcxz SKIP_GWIAZD` after `mov cx, ax` and actual `SKIP_GWIAZD:` just before end of program which is `koniec:` but it still does not work.
I did it this way because the last thing in last line are only letters, so we do not want to have anything after that (next line nor empty spaces). – sakcaj 7 mins ago

Comment: But you can't just skip to end, because you have still some values in stack, etc.. and I would *want* to print new_line. What is probably giving you headache is the print of spaces, as those belong to next line. I would suggest you to move spaces as first thing, and "output" `0` spaces (in the same way how the gwiazdy will be skipped for `0`), so the code inside loop will have human logic: `<0-6 spaces><ABCD><6-0 stars><newline>`.

Comment: Actually then you can calculate `number_of_stars` as `(6-number_of_spaces)`, so you can even save one counter, if you want to trade it for short calculation.  ... btw, if you really did jump to "`koniec:`", then it should work even with corrupted stack. So I don't know what doesn't work on it, debugging is your task... ;)

Comment: Oh, obviously using `ax` as star counter can't work since the beginning, as you then do `mov ah,02h` for printing the character, so `ax` is no more `6`, but `518` (plus `al` is probably modified by `int 21h`). But you didn't mention that "tiny" problem in your question, which makes me wonder how you test/debug this code. Maybe invest few hours firstly into learning how to use some debugger effectively, before continuing with Assembly learning. It's like 10-1000x more difficult to learn Assembly programming, if you can't debug the code live, step by step, and watch how CPU works.

Comment: You are right, Jose pointed that below and the easiest fix was to just use different registers to store main values. 

As I said, that's actually 2nd time I am doing anything in assembler, 1st time was 3 weeks ago after short introduction during studies. 

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Ah, I probably finally understood... you have seen lot of stars (already initial 518 or how many there are), and correctly found one of the bugs when `ax` should have been theoretically zero, thus creating 64k loop (not infinite one). You definitely should invest time into basic debugger usage, you would see the wrong `cx` for stars already at first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the registers you are using : `AX` and `CX` are used for interrupts and loops, so you can use other registers, for example, `SI` instead of `CX` and `DI` instead of `AX` :

```
kod segment
org 100h
assume cs:kod

start:
mov si,3        ;◄■■ INSTEAD OF CX.
mov bx,3
mov di,6        ;◄■■ INSTEAD OF AX.

mov ah, 02h

    PETLA_ZEW:

    mov cx,4
    mov dl, 'A'

        PETLA_CIAG:

            int 21h
            inc dl
            dec cx

        jnz PETLA_CIAG

    cmp di, 0   ;◄■■ IF COUNTER == 0 ...
    je  koniec  ;◄■■ ... NO MORE ASTERISKS.

    mov cx, di  ;◄■■
    mov dl, '*'

        PETLA_GWIAZD:

            int 21h
            dec cx

        jnz PETLA_GWIAZD

    sub di, 3        ;◄■■

    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h

    push bx
    mov cx, bx
    mov dl, '_'
        PETLA_SPACJE:

            int 21h
            dec bx

        jnz PETLA_SPACJE

    pop bx
    add bx, 3

    dec si       ;◄■■
    jnz PETLA_ZEW

koniec:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
kod ends
end start
```

Comment: @sakcaj, I replaced spaces ' ' by underscores '_' for testing purposes :)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like you are right. But how do I know which registers I can use? Are they by default all "empty" and it just depends on the program I write? Could I for example use only EDX,DX,DH,DL  and CX to count? There's so much about it in the internet...

Comment: @sakcaj, some registers are used for interrupts, others are used for some instructions (like loop), it takes time to learn when and how to use which registers, but, if you are not using certain register, you can give it some use, like counter.

Comment: @sakcaj you can use any register you wish, but some of them have special purpose (for example keep `sp` working as stack pointer) for certain instructions, and in 16b mode some are allowed for memory addressing, and some not, etc. It' not like you can't use the `ax` for counter. It's calling `int 21h` which ruins it, and that you have to verify by reading documentation of everything, what you call, or use one of ABIs, which does specify what may change, and what not. Also `dl/dh` are part of `dx` and that's part `edx`, it's not like 4 separate registers, but 8/16/32 bits parts of the same one.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will keep it in mind to check the purpose of registers I want to use next time before I will use them :).